# Data type conversion in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

This is my program. It takes input of two strings, calculates their length, checks if the lengths are equal. If the lengths are equal it reverses the first string and checks if it is equal to second or not. If the lengths are not equal or the strings are not same after reversing them the program prints `"String is not palindrome"` otherwise `"String is palindrome"`. I know this is not the actual palindrome type solution but this is what I wanted to do.

The problem: The `STRLEN1` variable I have created is actually a `DB` type and so it gives an `"Operand types do not match"` error.

Possible solution: Create another variable of the `DD` or `DW` type and store the value from `STRLEN1` to the newly created `STRLEN1_ DW` variable. This is what the problem is, I don't know how to do it.

After searching a lot on google this is what I found https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/453.shtml and tried to use it, but only got one more error added to the list: `NEED EXPRESSION`. I am not sure how to solve this one.

```
DATA SEGMENT
        STR1 DB 'ENTER STRING ONE : $'
        STR2 DB 'ENTER STRING TWO : $'
    STR_PALIN DB "STRING IS PALINDROME$"
    STR_NOT_PALIN DB "STRING IS NOT PALINDROME$"
        INSTR1 DB 20 DUP("$")
    INSTR2 DB 20 DUP("$")
        RSTR DB 20 DUP("$")
        NEWLINE DB 10,13,"$"
    STRLEN1 DB 0
    STRLEN2 DB 0
    STRLEN1_ DW 0
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
        ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA

START:
        MOV AX, DATA
        MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX

    LEA SI, INSTR1
    LEA DI, INSTR2

;GET STRING
    MOV AH, 09H
        LEA DX, STR1
        INT 21H

        MOV AH, 0AH
        MOV DX, SI
        INT 21H

        MOV AH, 09H
        LEA DX, NEWLINE
        INT 21H

;GET LENGTH OF STRING ONE
    MOV BL, INSTR1+1
    ADD BL, 30H
    MOV STRLEN1, BL

;TAKE SECOND INPUT OF THE STRING
        MOV AH, 09H
        LEA DX, STR2
        INT 21H

        MOV AH, 0AH
        MOV DX, DI
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,NEWLINE
        INT 21H

;GET LENGTH OF STRING 2
    MOV BL, INSTR2+1
    ADD BL, 30H
    MOV STRLEN2, BL

;COMPARE STRING LENGTH
    MOV CX, 6
    MOV AL, STRLEN1
    MOV BL, STRLEN2
    CMP AL, BL
    JNE NOT_PALIN

;REVERSE STRING ONE
    MOV STRLEN1 -> STRLEN1_
    MOV CX, STRLEN1
    MOV CX, -2
    LEA DI, RSTR

    ADD SI, STRLEN1
    ADD SI, -2

    L1:
        MOV AL, [SI]
        MOV [DI], AL
        DEC SI
        INC DI
        LOOP L1
        MOV AL, [SI]
        MOV [DI], AL
        INC DI
        MOV DL, '$'
        MOV [DI], DL
        MOV CX, STRLEN1

    LEA SI, RSTR
    LEA DI, INSTR2

    REPE CMPSB
    JNE NOT_PALIN
    JMP PALIN

    NOT_PALIN:
        MOV AH, 09H
        LEA DX, STR_NOT_PALIN
        INT 21H
        JMP EXIT

    PALIN:
        MOV AH, 09H
        LEA DX, STR_PALIN
        INT 21H
        JMP EXIT

    EXIT:
        MOV AX, 4CH
        INT 21H

CODE ENDS
END START
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are having trouble initializing the 16-bit CX register with a byte-sized value. There are a couple of ways you can do that - the most straight forward is probably:

```
  XOR CX, CX     ; set CX to zero
  MOV CL, STRLEN
```

CX is now equal to STRLEN.

Comment: It does solves that one error but two other <code>"Operand types do not match"</code> errors one on <code>ADD SI, STRLEN1</code> and last line under L1: <code>MOV CX, STRLEN1</code> still show up. Should the same be done from them as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to copy `STRLEN1` to `STRLEN1_` you could do:

```
MOVZX AX, BYTE PTR [STRLEN1] ; Zero-extend STRLEN1 into AX
MOV [STRLEN1_], AX
```

*Or*, you could simply define `STRLEN1` as `db 0,0` and keep the high byte clear.

```
MOV [STRLEN1], BL
ADD SI, WORD PTR [STRLEN1]   ; Whether WORD PTR needs to be specified depends
                             ; on the assembler
```

Comment: I am not really so good at assembly, could you please make changes to my real program and guide me?

Comment: Just replace your `MOV STRLEN1 -> STRLEN1_` line with the first pair of instructions I showed and it should work fine (save for any other problems you might have in your code).

Comment: `MOVZX AX, BYTE PTR [STRLEN1] ; Zero-extend STRLEN1 into AX` gives me error `"Illegal instruction for currently selected processor(s)"`

Comment: `MOVZX` requires at least an 80386. If you can't use 80386 instructions you could replace the `MOVZX` with `MOV AL,[STRLEN1]` `MOV AH,0`

Answer (score 0):

Could you use data words instead of bytes for STRLEN1 and STRLEN2? It doesn't look like that would break your code, and it would save you the trouble of doing the conversion.

Comment: No, they would generate error when I am trying to move the string length from BL registers to them.